# How can I run a Java .class file or .jar file on an Android phone?

Tags: java, android, class, jar

How can I run a Java .class file or .jar file on my Android phone?

I am currently learning Java programming using the Java SE standard. I have generated .class files using javac and created a .jar file using the "java -jar" command. Now, I want to run these .class or .jar files on my Android phone. Is there an app that can conveniently run .class files or execute .jar files on Android, so that I can see the results on my phone?

Comment: I found an app on Google Play called "Java Runtime Environment" that can run .class files and .jar files.

Comment: This will explain all the tools normally used (usually one uses an IDE - Integrated Development Environment): https://developer.android.com/build/building-cmdline

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert .class file to .dex format as android uses a different byte code format.
You can find more about it [here.](https://www.javatpoint.com/dalvik-virtual-machine)

I assume you already have an android project created.
You can then include the .dex file in your project.
Finally, you can load and execute the file as you need.

In case you need similar approach for loading .dex files you can find that [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75717441/how-to-load-a-dex-file-using-dex-dexclassloader)

Following is an example code which might help you to figure it out.

```
import dalvik.system.DexClassLoader;

public class DynamicClassRunner {
  
  public static void runDexFile() {
        try {
            // Get the path to the .dex file (place it in the "assets" folder)
            String dexPath = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/myjavafile.dex";
            
        // Get the application's class loader
        ClassLoader parentClassLoader = context.getClassLoader();

        // Create a new DexClassLoader to load the .dex file
        DexClassLoader dexClassLoader = new DexClassLoader(dexPath, null, null, parentClassLoader);

        // Replace "com.example.MyJavaClass" with the actual class name you want to run
        Class<?> myClass = dexClassLoader.loadClass("com.example.MyJavaClass");
        
        // Create an instance of the class (assuming it has a parameterless constructor)
        Object instance = myClass.newInstance();
        
        // If the class has a method to execute, you can call it like this:
        // myClass.getMethod("methodName").invoke(instance);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```